# My regular expression is not getting matched exactly in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Here's my code...

```
import re

l=["chap","chap11","chapa","chapb","chapc","chap3","chap2","chapf","chap4","chap55","chapf","chap33","chap54","chapgk"]
for i in l:
    matchobj=re.match(r'chap[0-9]',i,re.M|re.I)
    if matchobj:
        print(i)
```

as I have mentioned chap[0-9].. so it should only those strings which follow only one integer after chap

so I should get the following output..

chap3
chap2
chap4

but I am getting the following output...
chap11
chap3
chap2
chap4
chap55
chap33
chap54

Comment: Add a word boundary `chap[0-9]\b`

Answer (score 3):

[`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) matches your pattern at the beginning of the string. Append e.g. end of string `'$'` or word boundary `'\b'` to your pattern:

```
matchobj=re.match(r'chap\d$',i,re.M|re.I)
# \d (digit) is shortcut for [0-9]
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) on `re.match`:

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance.

Comment: You can simplify number range by using `\d`.

Comment: @Niitaku I added this as it shortens the pattern and usually makes no semantic difference. However, `\d` can match more characters than `[0-9]`

Answer (score 1):

You should add a dollar sign to the end of your regex expression. The dollar ($) means the end of the string, and for future reference, the carat (^) signifies the beginning.

```
import re

l=["chap","chap11","chapa","chapb","chapc","chap3","chap2","chapf","chap4","chap55","chapf","chap33","chap54","chapgk"]
for i in l:
    matchobj=re.match(r'chap[0-9]$',i,re.M|re.I)
    if matchobj:
        print(i)
```

Output

```
chap3
chap2
chap4
```

Comment: But it should match only 1 integer right after chap...here why it isn't?